# What is the yarn alternative of npm-shrinkwrap?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarn-workspaces, shrinkwrap

The `npm-shrinkwrap` ensures that installed packages also have the same version of dependencies that was used at the moment of publishing to the registry (These versions are stated in the `npm-shrinkwrap` which is then used on installation).

I am currently using yarn (and lerna for publishing) and working on a monorepo project with workspaces. Now I would like to have each package in the monorepo have same guarantees provided by `npm-shrinkwrap`.

One shortcoming of the `npm-shrinkwrap` is that it does not support workspaces. Hence I cannot use `npm-shrinkwrap` since it is only created at the root and does not influence how individual packages in the monorepo get installed.

Since I am using `yarn`, I was wondering if there is an alternative to `npm-shrinkwrap` in yarn?

Or maybe a better question is, using yarn/lerna, how do I lock version dependencies for publication, such that when my packages in the mono-repo are downloaded, they are downloaded with the exact versions of dependencies (and transitive dependencies) that was specified at the point of publication?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following in the yarn docs (classic yarn 1.x)

> If you are using an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file right now, be aware that you may end up with a different set of dependencies. Yarn does not support npm shrinkwrap files as they don’t have enough information in them to power Yarn’s more deterministic algorithm. If you are using a shrinkwrap file it may be easier to convert everyone working on the project to use Yarn at the same time. Simply remove your existing `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file and check in the newly created `yarn.lock` file.

From here:
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm